# Redux store doesn't update on first button click

Tags: reactjs, redux, jsx, state-management, react-bootstrap-table

I want to use redux but still control what's being rendered in bootstrap-react-table through my local state. So, in componentDidMount I'm fetching my data and when I try to filter through a button click I setState to a field named "itemsToDisplay", which I then want to serve as data to the table. But the click only works the second time around, and when I log the state in render/componentDidMount it's undefined.

I've tried different conditions for rendering the items in the table's data field prop, yet unsuccessful. I've also tried setting state in componentWillMount.

```
class Deliveries extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      itemsToDisplay: this.props.deliveries,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getDeliveries();
    this.setState(prev => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        itemsToDisplay: this.props.deliveries,
      }
    })
  }

  filterUndelivered = () => {
    this.props.filterUndelivered();
    this.setState(prev => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        itemsToDisplay: this.props.undelivered_items,
      }
    })
  };

  getFilters = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button className="m-1" color="primary">By time</Button>
        <Button className="m-1" color="primary" onClick={ this.filterUndelivered }>Not delivered</Button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { itemsToDisplay } = this.state;

    const options = {
      insertBtn: this.createCustomInsertButton,
      searchField: this.createCustomSearchField,
    };

    return (
      <div className="animated fadeIn">

        <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <div className="font-weight-bold mt-2">Deliveries Monitor</div>
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-end">
            {this.getFilters()}
          </div>
        </div>
        <BootstrapTable
          data={ itemsToDisplay ? itemsToDisplay : this.props.deliveries }
          version="4"
          search
          hover
          pagination
          bordered={false}
          headerStyle={{ background: "#20a8d8" }}
          bodyStyle={{ cursor: "pointer"}}
          options={ options }
        >
          <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField="delivery_id">Delivery#</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="seller">Seller</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="address">Address</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="site">Site</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="end_of_window">End of window</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="due_date">Due date</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="status">Status</TableHeaderColumn>
        </BootstrapTable>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    deliveries: state.deliveriesReducer.deliveries,
    undelivered_items: state.deliveriesReducer.undelivered_items,
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({ getDeliveries, filterUndelivered }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Deliveries);
```

The expected result is to be able to filter on the first click, when the condition to the data prop is correct.

Comment: I had the same problem in the past. Did you check your data flow from Redux?

Comment: I did. All the way from the action and back from the reducer the data seems fine and the component receives it properly. For some reason, the first click leaves "itemsToDisplay" as undefined and then does its work correctly on the 2nd click.

Comment: any chance that it is a synchronisation problem?

Comment: try with  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your code like below :

```
  filterUndelivered = () => {
    this.props.filterUndelivered();
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps = nextProps => {
    if (nextProps.undelivered_items !== undefined) {
      this.setState({ itemsToDisplay: nextProps.undelivered_items });
    }
  };
```

Also install Redux dev tools in browser and analyse application state .It may give you more insight about the issue.

Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd

Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reduxdevtools/

Comment: I tried it and the logic still functions the same: 1st click no go, 2nd click works.

Comment: did you tired with dev tools..Are you seeing data on first click in state?

Comment: Yeah, in Redux devtools the state changes after the first click and store is updated properly.

Comment: getting callback in componentWillReceiveProps  on first click?..add some console log and see

Comment: Actually, I managed to solve it through @prasobh.kollattu's answer, but notice that the setState function also needs a spread for the previous state to be exact:

`componentWillReceiveProps = nextProps => {
    if (nextProps.undelivered_items !== undefined) {
      this.setState(prev => {
        return {
          ...prev,
          itemsToDisplay: nextProps.undelivered_items
        }
      });
    }
  };
`

Answer (score 0):

Perform simple check whether data is available or not before loading it to the table

```
{
  itemsToDisplay.lenght > 0 &&
    <BootstrapTable
              data={ itemsToDisplay }
              version="4"
              search
              hover
              pagination
              bordered={false}
              headerStyle={{ background: "#20a8d8" }}
              bodyStyle={{ cursor: "pointer"}}
              options={ options }
            >
              <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField="delivery_id">Delivery#</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="seller">Seller</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="address">Address</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="site">Site</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="end_of_window">End of window</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="due_date">Due date</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="status">Status</TableHeaderColumn>
            </BootstrapTable>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you having another source of truth (state) within your component? Basically it's a bad practice to store your props in you component state (of course there are cases, but I don't think you need it here).

I think your component should receive only single `items` prop which would show either delivered or undelivered items. Your actions would be responsible for passing in deliver or undelivered items in your `items` prop based on some kind of filter that you would set in your getDeliveries/filterUndelivered actions.

That way you would always pass `items` prop to your `BootstrapTable` `data` prop and your redux would be responsible for passing correct items (delivered or undelivered) in your component `items` prop.

Another advantage of this approach is if you would add another kind of filter to your items (lets say search query), then you would just expand your redux filter state and add `searchQuery` property. With that you would easily apply that new filter to your items and your component basically wouldn't need any changes.

[Here](https://redux.js.org/basics/example) is simple todo example with simple filtering that you could apply for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, may be this can help

```
...
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getDeliveries();    
}
...
componentWillReceiveProps(recievedProps) {
    if (this.props.deliveries != recievedProps.deliveries) {
        this.setState({
            itemsToDisplay: recievedProps.deliveries
        })
    }
}
...
```